# Implementing a queue for a digicode-like system

Tags: python, python-2.7, queue, pyside

I have a system with `QPushButtons` that is to work like a digicode doors. Each button has an ID (integer). When the last buttons you have pushed correspond to a given password, things happen (like the doors gets open).

I'm thinking of using a queue to implement this, with a pointer to the last value added. But how can I test if the password is correct ?

Here is the code I have yet :

```
class MyQueue():
    def __init__(self, size, defaultValue=None):
        self.size = size
        self.content = [defaultValue]*size
        self.end = self.size-1
    def addItem(self, value):
        self.end = (self.end+1)%self.size
        self.content[self.end] = value
    def checkCorrect(self, password):
        pass #???
```

I can fill the queue, `size` is the number of items that are saved. But I don't know how to check if the password is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to read the password backwards, starting from the last value added. Check for each character/number in the password if it is correct. If you can read the password until the end, you're good. Here is what I'd go with :

```
    def checkCorrect(self, password):
        pw = list(reversed(password))
        i = 0
        j = self.end
        if len(pw) > self.size:
            return False
        while True:
            if pw[i] <> self.content[j]:
                return False
            else:
                i += 1
                j = (j-1)%self.size
                if i == len(pw):
                    return True
```